# question about green theorems

Tags: calculus

I want to compute the line integral

$$ \int_{\gamma} (e^x \sin y) dx + (e^x \cos y) dy $$

where $\gamma$ is one loop counterclockwise on the ellipse $x^2 + xy + y^2=1 $

My effort:

Since we are on a closed loop we can apply GReen's theorem. LEt $M(x,y) = e^x \sin y $ and $N(x,y) = e^x \cos y $. Then

$$ N_x = e^x \cos y $$and

$$ M_y = e^x \cos y $$

Hence, by greens theorem

$$ \int_{\gamma} (e^x \sin y) dx + (e^x \cos y) dy  = \int \int_{Ellipse} N_x - M_y = 0 $$

is this correct?

Comment: sorry. I fixed it!

Comment: Indeed, this seems right.

Comment: Also note that the integral over *any* simple closed curved is zero. The equation defining curve $\gamma$ is entirely superfluous.